# restricted domain for parabola to find surface of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration

For the parabola $y=x^2-4$ how can I change the equation so that the domain is restricted to $[-2,2]$ or the range is restricted to $[0,-\infty]$? But it must be in terms of y only so that the closed portion can be revolved around the x axis and I can find an equation for that surface. Essentially I need an equation for only the part of the parabola below the x axis.

Comment: $y=x^2-4$ where $x \in [-2,2]$ and $y=0$ otherwise

Comment: If you are integrating, the domain/range can be given as the bounds of integration.

Answer (score 3):

$$y = 
\begin{cases} 
x^2 - 4, &x\in [-2, 2] \\ \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \\  
\end{cases}
$$

The domain you want is $x \in [-2, 2]$. The range you want is $y\in [-4, 0]$.

I'm not clear what you mean by "change the equation": you can do so by defining, as above:

$y = x^2 - 4$ precisely when $x \in [-2,2]$, otherwise $y = 0$.

In other words, $-4 \leq y = x^2 - 4 \leq 0$.